# urllib2.urlopen don't work with separate threads

Tags: python

I'm working on an application to download the code of a web page and captures the links.
It works, but if I connect the program to a GUI, it locks the corresponding button until the download is completed.

If I trigger the download via a separate thread, to avoid the button lock, it just freezes and does not complete execution.

Is this normal? Or am I missing something?

Below goes the snippet of code. If I call grab() from a separate thread, nothing happens, neither errors.

The function update_observers() only notifies the observers, not doing else.
The observer is the responsible by making any changes, in this case, redraw the GUI.

```
def grab(self, url):        
        try:
            self._status = 'Downloading page.'
            self.update_observers()
            inpu = urllib2.urlopen(url)

        except URLError, e:
            self._status = 'Error: '+ e.reason
            self.update_observers()
            return None

        resp = []  
        self._status = 'Parsing links'
        self.update_observers()
        for line in inpu.readlines():
            for reg in self._regexes:
                links = reg.findall(line)
                for link in links:
                    resp.append(link)

        self._status = 'Ready.'
        self.update_observers()
        return resp
```

This code is called here:

```
def grab(self, widget):
    t = Thread(target=self.work)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

def work(self):
    print "Working"
    self.links = None
    self.links = self.grabber.grab(self.txtLink.get_text())
    for link in self.links:
        self.store.append([link])
    print "Ok."
```

If I move the code from work() to grab, removing the threading stuff, it's all ok.

Comment: What does `self.update_observers()` do? If it tries to interact with the GUI at all then you may not be able to call it from a separate thread.

Comment: It forces a GUI update, but I tried without it, with the same results.
On another program that I have(a interface for MEncoder) this approach worked well.

Comment: Your problem sounds like a synchronization issue, but your snippet does not contain any threading code.  Can you show us how you start the thread and what `update_observers()` does to report status updates?

Comment: I forgot to mention, but in debug mode the same code works perfectly. I use SPE with WinPDB.

Answer (score 0):

I just called `gtk.gdk.threads_init()` before `gtk.main()` and everything worked perfectly without any changes.